# SimpleMembership in Multitenant Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multi-tenant, simplemembership

While using `SimpleMembership` i realized that it is not supporting my MultiTanant Architecture

**My DB Structure** 
I have seperate user tables in each schema and i also want UserInRoles table in those schemas

**Problem**  
When `SimpleMembership` initializes DB like this

```
 WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("connectionstring", "users", "userID", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

It creates 4 more tables in schema `dbo`. 
It cannot create tables in other schemas. Is there any hack or custom way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360126/simplemembership-with-custom-database-schema-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

> I asked the same question to the product team.The design goal of SIMPLE membership was to work out-of-the box as simple as possible.

**But** if you are using Entity framework to generate your DB then you can do that simply by including

```
[Table("webpages_Membership", Schema = "SchemaNameHere")]
```

Check this [link](http://devproconnections.com/entity-framework/working-schema-names-entity-framework-code-first-design) for a sample on how to do that

Comment: i am not using Entity Framework. I am using simple db approach

Comment: maybe you could try some workaround like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244131/websecurity-initializedatabaseconnection-how-specify-a-db-schema